# Anyone know how to remove/hide the [ 00/00/0000] Date from the date input field?

Tags: visualforce, date, slds

[image]

I'm just wanting to hide/remove todays date at it serves no purpose in my form any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That span appears to have a class of "dateFormat" put on it from SFDC so you can try

```
.dateFormat {display:none !important;}
```